# Сложности с установкой expo для react-native

Tags: npm, react-native, expo

Нужна ваша помощь. Хочу работать вместе с react-native. Для этого я беру и устанавливаю expo. Но постоянно я получаю вот такие ошибки, как и на картинке. Даже после такого установления, пытаюсь создать react-native приложение, но мне говорит что такой команды, как expo нет. Версия node.js - 16.7.0. Как мне избавиться от этих ошибок и установить expo для react-native. Спасибо

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: 1. просьба задавать вопросы на русском языке. 2. приложите лог ошибки текстом, картинку сложнее изучать.

Comment: Это не ошибки, а предупреждения и можно почитать, что они относятся к различным модулям node, которые у вас установлены. Думаю, что кто работает с react native просто не обращают на них внимание

Comment: @Dmitry, Я понимаю это, но суть в том, что когда я создаю react-native приложение с помощью команды `expo init my-app --template=blank` , мне пишет, что такой команды как `expo` не существует. Даже при создании приложения через IntelliJ IDEA, в консоли у меня те же ошибки и приложение вообще не запускается

Comment: @Ronald значит смотреть надо в сторону установки expo. То что вы показываете это npm. А установка expo сделана? Какое именно решение установлено? expo-cli может быть? Если expo установлен, но при этом винда ругается, то дело совершенно не в этих логах

Comment: @Dmitry, В том то и дело, чтобы установить expo-cli надо прописать эту команду. У меня самый expo-cli не устанавливается

Comment: @Ronald ну оф доки говорят, что установка вот такая `npm install --global expo-cli` в глобальное окружение. При этом должны быть git и node.js. Попробуйте

Comment: @Dmitry, У меня оно устанавливается в путь `Admin / AppData / Roaming / npm`. Когда я пытаюсь на диске d создать приложение с помощью команды `expo init my_app --template = blank` оно мне говорит, что `cannot find module 'C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\expo-cli\bin\expo.js'`.

Comment: @Ronald Будьте добры, вставьте все это в ваш вопрос. Ваши действия и результаты их. Только избегайте принтискринов с текстом. Копируйте ваши команды, логи в вопрос, используя специальные блоки для кода. Чтобы исправить нажмите ссылку [Править](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/posts/1333984/edit) под самим вопросом